# Calculation not working (android studio)

Tags: android, math, formula

I have the following code, that calculates Body Fat for an App I'm writing, I don't know why the result is alway NaN when pressing the "Calculate" button, if anyone can help, I'll be very thankfull!

```
String total1;

public void contaBfMasc(View v) {
    double alt2, cint2, pesco2;
    double conta;
    EditText alt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.altura);
    EditText cint1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cintura);
    EditText pesco1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pescoco);
    TextView Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalBfMasc);

    alt2 = Float.parseFloat(alt1.getText().toString());
    cint2 = Float.parseFloat(cint1.getText().toString());
    pesco2 = Float.parseFloat(pesco1.getText().toString());

    conta = 495/(1.0324-0.19077*(Math.log10(cint2-pesco2))+0.15456*(Math.log10(alt2)))-450;
    total1 = String.format("%.2f", conta); 
    Result.setText(total1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The `java.lang.Math.log10(double a)` method returns the base 10 logarithm of a double value, `a`. Applicable special case:
If `a` is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN.**

I suspect that at least one of `{alt2, cint2, pesco2}` is `NaN`, or `(cint2-pesco2) < 0`.

Comment: Exact! It was alt2 returning NaN! Thank you very much! It's solved now!

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.